# Google Apps Script conflict between global and local variables workaround

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use two scripts on one sheet. Unfortunately, due to the fact that the second one works globally, the work of the first one is disrupted.

The first script creates a formula that operates on a range of cells in a column and outputs the cell colors in hex values.

```
function getHax(input) {
    return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(input).getBackgrounds();
}
```

[image: Here's how it works]

The second one (thanks to @Tanaike) creates a custom menu with a table of contents that is assembled from cells beginning with [S] in column B:B.It also collects the number of words in each chapter by adding the values from column X:X (where words are counted by a special formula) between chapters. At the end, it allows you to jump to the desired chapter by clicking on it in the menu.

```
onOpen();

function onOpen(e) {
  if (e) return;
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var menu = ui.createMenu('Scripts');
  var submenu = ui.createMenu('Go to');
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("B1:B" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var values = range.getValues();
  var startRow = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var value = values[i][0];
    if (value.startsWith("[S]")) {
      if (startRow != 0) {
        var sum = sheet.getRange("X" + startRow + ":X" + (i - 1)).getValues().reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b[0]; }, 0);
        submenu.addItem(values[startRow - 1][0] + " (" + sum + ")", "goToCell" + (startRow - 1));
      }
      var cell = sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1);
      this["goToCell" + i] = function(cell) { return function() { cell.activate(); } }(cell);
      startRow = i + 1;
    }
  }
  if (startRow != 0) {
    var sum = sheet.getRange("X" + startRow + ":X" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b[0]; }, 0);
    submenu.addItem(values[startRow - 1][0] + " (" + sum + ")", "goToCell" + (startRow - 1));
    this["goToCell" + (startRow - 1)] = function() { return function() { SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").activate(); } }();
  }
  menu.addSubMenu(submenu);
  menu.addToUi();
}
```

[image: Here's how it works]

Because the second script uses global variables, it conflicts with the first one.
So, when I try to use them at the same time, the second script works while the first one breaks.

And when I try to use the formula to display the colors in the range, I get:
*Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context. (5).*

Is there any workaround that will allow to use both scripts on the same sheet?

Thanks for any help anyone can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, as a simple workaround, how about using try-catch as follows?

#### Modified script:

```js
function getHax(input) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(input).getBackgrounds();
}

onOpen();

function onOpen(e) {
  if (e) return;
  try {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var menu = ui.createMenu('Scripts');
    var submenu = ui.createMenu('Go to');
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange("B1:B" + sheet.getLastRow());
    var values = range.getValues();
    var startRow = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
      var value = values[i][0];
      if (value.startsWith("[S]")) {
        if (startRow != 0) {
          var sum = sheet.getRange("X" + startRow + ":X" + (i - 1)).getValues().reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b[0]; }, 0);
          submenu.addItem(values[startRow - 1][0] + " (" + sum + ")", "goToCell" + (startRow - 1));
        }
        var cell = sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1);
        this["goToCell" + i] = function (cell) { return function () { cell.activate(); } }(cell);
        startRow = i + 1;
      }
    }
    if (startRow != 0) {
      var sum = sheet.getRange("X" + startRow + ":X" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().reduce(function (a, b) { return a + b[0]; }, 0);
      submenu.addItem(values[startRow - 1][0] + " (" + sum + ")", "goToCell" + (startRow - 1));
      this["goToCell" + (startRow - 1)] = function () { return function () { SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").activate(); } }();
    }
    menu.addSubMenu(submenu);
    menu.addToUi();
  } catch (e) {
    // console.log(e); // If you wan to confirm the error message, please use this.
  }
}
```

- By this modification, even when an error occurs at `onOpen` by running your custom function, the script is not stopped by an error.